# GetOperation in google API

Tags: python, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am using `dialogflow` python package to communicate to my dialogflow agent (`v2` version). I call the `train_agent` function and get the `google.api_core.operation.Operation` object. I store the `name` attribute of the `operation` in DB for later use. How do I get the new status of the same `operation`?

I tried using `from google.longrunning import GetOperation` but it says `ImportError: cannot import name GetOperation`. And the docs say `Any API service that returns long-running operations should implement the Operations interface so developers can have a consistent client experience.`

Should I implement the interface or something?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Read that and understood. Will take care from ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using `AgentsClient()` object to get access to an operations client.

The final code:

```
agent_client = dialogflow_v2.AgentsClient()
operations_obj = agent_client.operations_client.get_operations(operations_full_path)
status = operations_obj.done
```

And other fields can be used as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your are confusing the Google Cloud Python client libraries with the underlying [Protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#what-are-protocol-buffers) and [gRPCs](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/) of the individual services. `GetOperation` is a rpc method of the `Operation` service, defined [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/6a3277c0656219174ff7c345f31fb20a90b30b97/google/longrunning/operations.proto#L54). It takes a `GetOperationRequest` message as input and returns an `Operation` message. Protobuf messages are meant to be compiled to native classes in various programming languages, in Python they actually end up being descriptors. The descriptors for all messages related to long running operations are shipped with the `google-api-core` library, which in turn is shipped with every Google Cloud Python client library (e.g. `dialogflow`). This is why you could technically use the protobuf descriptors directly by importing them from the client library:

```
from google.longrunning.operations_pb2 import Operation
```

You would then only have to generate gRPC client and server stubs and you are ready to go:)

In real life you should of course ignore all of this (including the `GetOperation` method and the `Operations` interface) and instead use the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained), of which there is one for each Google Cloud service in each of the major programming languages and which all come with core modules for common tasks like authentication, billing and long-running operations management. These libraries abstract the Protobuf/gRPC stuff for end users.

In your case you would want to have a look at the [`google.api_core.operations_v1.OperationsClient`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/operations_client.html), which you can use to manage instances of [`google.api_core.operation.Operation`](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/operation.html).

A different question is however if you really need this at all. I have never seen training a Dialogflow agent take more then a few seconds, and once the agent is set up it is also not something that has to be done over and over again. Do you really have to manage this operation manually and even store metadata about it in an external database?